# RMI ConnectException : Connection refused, really strange behaviour

Tags: java, rmi

I know that this question has been asked several times but I've yet to find an answer that works for me. Basically I've implemented a client/server solution with RMI. My only problem is that connection to the server is sometimes extremely slow.

When the server is started and a client connects, for the first time, it will take seconds before it gets connected (sometimes it does not even connect but get the ConnectException instead) and after that I will get the Connection refused when trying to communicate with the server.
What makes it even more mind boggling is that it works perfectly fine when I disconnect the first failing client and connect again. The client then connects in under a second and all the communication works flawlessy.

I've tried manually starting the rmiregistry, I've double checked my PATH. I wasn't able to connect to the port with telnet but it works when I play on that port with my Othello game (which is not using RMI). It might be worth to say that I'm doing this on the same network and computer so I'm using localhost.

TL;DR: When I first connect to the server it takes forever, but I'm able to connect. When I then try to communicate with methods it crashes and I receive "java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.xxx.xxx.x; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect". If I then close that client and try to connect with another client it takes around one second to connect and then everything works flawlessy. Why is that?

Code for the client:

```
public class NetworkClient {
private Registry registry;
private IArenaServer server;

public NetworkClient(String ipAddress, int port) throws RemoteException {

    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
        System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
    }

    try {

        registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(ipAddress, port);
        server = (IArenaServer)(registry.lookup("arenaServer"));
        System.out.println("Client successfully connected to server at " + ipAddress + ":" + "port");

    } catch (NotBoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NetworkClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (AccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NetworkClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Code for the server:

```
public class ArenaServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IArenaServer {

private int port = 9029;
private String ipAddress;
private Registry registry;

public ArenaServer() throws RemoteException {

    if(System.getSecurityManager() == null){
        System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
    }

//  try {
        //ipAddress = (InetAddress.getLocalHost()).toString();
        registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
        registry.rebind("arenaServer", this);

        System.out.println("Server successfully started...");
        //System.out.println("Server's IP address is: " + ipAddress);

//  } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
//      ErrorHandler.getInstance().reportError("Cannot get IP address", "");
//  }
}
```

Generic example of what I get when trying to communicate with the server after connecting the first time:

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.xxx.xxx.x; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at $Proxy0.getInstalledGames(Unknown Source)
....
```

Comment: There is no 'connect to server' step here. All you're doing so far is connecting to the Registry and doing a lookup. If you get connection refusals doing that, either you have a firewall problem or the Registry isn't running. The server code you posted does not compile. If you get some other kinds of ConnectException you need to tell us what it is.

Comment: What do you mean with no 'connect to server' step? I can connect to the server but it is really slow/crashes the first time. When you close the failing client and connect with a new it works flawlessy.

I've added some more code to the Server and Client that should make it a bit more clearer. I also get the same error when I go and start the rmiregistry.exe in jre\bin. Windows firewall is off.

Comment: I've already said what I meant. The connect step happens when you call a remote method on the server via the remote stub: your code above doesn't do that.

Comment: I see, sorry if I misunderstood you. Well, basically the error happens when I'm calling the remote method via the stub. I'm doing List<Game> installedGames = frameController.getServer().getInstalledGames(); where getInstalledGames is the remote method and getServer returns the stub.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a case for java.rmi.server.hostname. See item A.1 in the RMI FAQ, reachable via the RMI Home Page.

Comment: I added  -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=ExternalIpHere to the Run Configuration of the Server and now it connects much faster. Though I'm still getting the "Connection refused" error when trying to call on the remote methods.

Comment: @Oakin Connection timeouts indicate network topology problems, not coding problems. Check that you have a clean IP route between clients and servers; check ping times; check that you can telnet from the clients to the appropriate ports on the servers; check firewalls, iptables etc rules at both client and server; ...

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure that there is nothing wrong with my code. I tried the application on a different network today and it didn't work. My friend tried it at his place and it worked perfectly for him. So it's either something weird with my computer or his network?

Comment: Might be of some help that the test at https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10220096 gave me null at both the addresses

Comment: @Oakin What test would that be? I contributed to that thread.

Comment: I noticed that. I'm referring to the code that 
Eric Kolotyluk wrote.